# How to set the height of a Material-UI's Grid item equals to its width responsively?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to make my grid items to be square, e.g. the height of the item equals to is width:

```
const App = ({ width, items }) => (
  <Grid container>
    {items.map((v) => (
      <Grid item md={width}> // I want to make this Grid to be square
        v
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
);
```

How to do that?
note: `width` is not fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would try to use CSS Grid for this layout, but if you want to use the Material UI Grid components, I believe you would have to do something with `paddingBottom: '100%'` and some tricks with absolute position.

Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-square-grid-using-mui-cy4p5

Comment: Thanks! but I cannot understand what you've done in `&::before` property. What is `content: "''"`? and what does `paddingBottom: 100%`?

Comment: `content: "''"` is usually just `content: ""` in regular CSS, but with JSS (which is what Material UI uses), you need the extra quotes: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11839#issuecomment-396881644

`paddingBottom: 100%` sets an amount of padding equal to 100% of the width of the container, which means you will have a square element.

Answer (score 1):

According to [material ui grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/)

you can achieve square box easily,
Do check below snippets

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    height: 100,

    width: 100,
  },
  control: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

export default function SpacingGrid() {
  const [spacing, setSpacing] = React.useState(2);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSpacing(Number(event.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Grid container justify="center" spacing={spacing}>
          {[0, 1, 2].map((value) => (
            <Grid key={value} item>
              <Paper className={classes.paper} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper className={classes.control}>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item>
              <FormLabel>spacing</FormLabel>
              <RadioGroup
                name="spacing"
                aria-label="spacing"
                value={spacing.toString()}
                onChange={handleChange}
                row
              >
                {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map((value) => (
                  <FormControlLabel
                    key={value}
                    value={value.toString()}
                    control={<Radio />}
                    label={value.toString()}
                  />
                ))}
              </RadioGroup>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! As far as I understand, it makes grid to be a square by setting fixed-size square paper. I want to know how to make the grid to be square on condition that `width` is not fixed.

Comment: set `width` to variable and assign it to `height` and `width`, This will work but I think it's not a good way. 
Can you give Lil a bit idea about what you are building, we can figure out a more effective and efficient way.

Comment: As I wrote, `width` is not actual size but it is a "Grid width" - number ranges from 1 to 12. So actual width that should be assigned to `height` is not same as `width` variable.

Comment: What I'm building is like a square grids container (like a chess board). Each grid items contain child react components.

Comment: If you are building something like a chessboard, I can help you with flex CSS if you need